# Difference between paired-end, mate-pair and long read

Tags: assembly, read-mapping, long-reads

I writing here because I have some questions for you.

I wondered what the essential differences were between `paired-end`, `mate-pair` and `long read`?

for me `mate-pair` and classic `paired-end` are both `paired-end reads`, with the difference that :

1. For classical `paired-end`: the insert size on classic paired-end is
   smaller (about 500bp)
2. while the insert size of `mate-pair` is much longer (several Kb)
   which allows to join the contiguous between them especially is it?

In revenge for the `long-reads`, I imagine that they are simply reads that are synthesized with a large read size but that do not allow like the maite-pair to make junctions between contigs?

Comment: https://www.biostars.org/p/467845/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all very different in separate regards, but they all refer to different wet-lab and sequencing protocols/technologies.

First, PE (paired end) reads are typically short (50-300) reads, most often Illumina HiSeq, MiSeq or NovaSeq protocols. Both pairs originate from a single fragment which is sequenced from either end:

```
------> PE1
-------------------------------- Fragment
                         <------ PE2
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        Insert
```

In contrast mate pairs arise from a fragment that is circularized before sequencing. Now imagine the fragment is circularized:

```
                     -----> MP1
....--------------------------------.......
          MP2 <-----
                    ^Circularized (joined) here
```

Long reads typically refer to PacBio or Oxford nanopore data, with very long reads lengths (up to several hundred kb).

Comment: thank you very much for your time, as you can see ATpoint gave a link where I also asked a question in respond to a post, sorry for the duplication...